# Update size of ScrollView item on tap gesture

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to update the size of a ScrollView item view on tap gesture but at the moment nothing seems to happen apart from the debugger logging the following:
`onChange(of: Optional<AnimalItem>) action tried to update multiple times per frame.`

The code is as follows:

```
struct AnimalItem: Identifiable, Equatable {
    private(set) var id: UUID = .init()
    var text: String
    var image: String
    var expanded = false
}

struct AnimalItemView: View {
    @State var item: AnimalItem
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(item.expanded ? item.image : item.text)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .frame(width: item.expanded ? 350 : 200, height: 250)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
    }
}

struct AnimalCarousalView: View {
    @State var items: [AnimalItem] = [
        .init(text: "A", image: "alligator"),
        .init(text: "B", image: "bear"),
        .init(text: "C", image: "cat")
    ]
    @State var selectedItem: AnimalItem?
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            LazyHStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
                    AnimalItemView(item: item)
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                        .onTapGesture {
                            selectedItem = item
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 250)
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
        .clipped()
        .onChange(of: selectedItem) { _ in
            withAnimation {
                selectedItem?.expanded.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is for the `Image` in `AnimalItemView` to expand in width when tapped and shrink when tapped again. Also at any time, I'd like for only one scroll item view to stay expanded. Currently, nothing happens when I tap on the view. Apart from this, I also seem to require the `clipShape` modifier applied to the `AnimalItemView` as well. If I don't, the `AnimalItemView` only seems to have a rounded clip for the bottom edges & the top edges appear flat. Finally, it doesn't seem correct to have the expansion property `expanded` be inside `AnimalItem`, though I might be wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: State should always be marked private.

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same result by just having a list of items and a selectedItems (like you are already doing) and determine whether one is expanded by comparing the selected item with the current item in the ForEach loop, basically getting rid of the expanded property and the onChange. I added a Binding property to the AnimalItemView to accomplish so.

```
struct AnimalItem: Identifiable, Equatable {
    private(set) var id: UUID = .init()
    var text: String
    var image: String
}

struct AnimalItemView: View {
    @State var item: AnimalItem
    @Binding var selectedItem: AnimalItem?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if item == selectedItem {
                Image(item.image)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: 350, height: 250)
            } else {
                Text(item.text)
                    .font(.title.bold())
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 250)
            }
        }
        .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: 10))
    }
}

struct AnimalCarouselView: View {
    @State var items: [AnimalItem] = [
        .init(text: "A", image: "Pic 1"),
        .init(text: "B", image: "Pic 2"),
        .init(text: "C", image: "Pic 3")
    ]
    @State var selectedItem: AnimalItem?
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            LazyHStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
                    AnimalItemView(item: item, selectedItem: $selectedItem)
                        .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: 10))
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation {
                                if selectedItem == item {
                                    selectedItem = nil
                                } else {
                                    selectedItem = item
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 250)
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
        .clipped()
        
    }
}
```

Tapping on the same item over and over again just sets the selectedItem to a given AnimalItem value or nil. Maybe, given how simple the code is as it is you could have kept using the expanded property, but if the project grows it would have been advisable to move it to a ViewModel/ObservableObject to keep track of the selected one.
Let me know your thoughts on this solution!

Comment: This worked, although the animation still needs smoothening but that is beyond the scope of the question. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. Maybe for that you could pass a different style of animation in withAnimation().

Comment: Yeah I couldn't figure out the specifics exactly but building on what I have I've posted another question with respect to the [animation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77880279/animate-swiftui-scrollview-item-from-left-edge)