# Animate SwiftUI Scrollview item from left edge

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Trying to recreate an animation similar to how Google displays an expanding effect on hovering an item on web/desktop but I haven't been able to nail the animation exactly.

The animation I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

This is what I have so far:

[image]

There are some issues I'm running into:

1. animation seems to happen from the center instead of the left edge with sort of a flash rather than an expand
2. title of the item to the right of the tapped item seems to overlap with the currently tapped item
3. the change of image of the item doesn't looks exactly the same, in Google's animation it looks like a fade in/out sort of effect rather than a mere replacement that happens in mine.

My code is as follows:

```
struct CarouselItem: Identifiable, Equatable {
    private(set) var id: UUID = .init()
    var title: String
    var year: String
    var runtime: String
    var certification: String
    var posterImage: String
    var stillImage: String
}

struct CarousalItemView: View {
    @State var item: CarouselItem
    @Binding var selectedItem: CarouselItem?
    
    var body: some View {
        if item.id == selectedItem?.id {
            selectedItemView()
        } else {
            unselectedItemView()
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder func selectedItemView() -> some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ZStack {
                Image(item.stillImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: 250, height: 200)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                    .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15) {
                            Spacer()
                            Text(item.title)
                                .font(.title2)
                            HStack {
                                Text("CBFC: " + item.certification)
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                                    .overlay {
                                        Rectangle()
                                            .stroke(.white, lineWidth: 1)
                                    }
                                Text(item.runtime)
                                Text(item.year)
                            }
                            .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 5, y: 5)
                            Button {
                                
                            } label: {
                                Text("Trailer")
                            }
                            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                            .tint(.gray)
                            .padding(.bottom, 15)
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                    }
            }
            Text(item.title)
                .frame(height: 50)
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder func unselectedItemView() -> some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Image(item.posterImage)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: 150, height: 200)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
            Text(item.title)
                .frame(height: 50)
        }
        .foregroundStyle(.white)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var items: [CarouselItem] = [
        .init(title: "Oppenheimer", year: "2023", runtime: "3h 1m", certification: "UA", posterImage: "poster1", stillImage: "still1"),
        .init(title: "Barbie", year: "2023", runtime: "1h 54m", certification: "PG", posterImage: "poster2", stillImage: "still2"),
        .init(title: "The Martian", year: "2015", runtime: "2h 24m", certification: "UA", posterImage: "poster3", stillImage: "still3"),
        .init(title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: "1994", runtime: "2h 22m", certification: "U", posterImage: "poster4", stillImage: "still4"),
        .init(title: "The Godfather", year: "1972", runtime: "2h 55m", certification: "UA", posterImage: "poster5", stillImage: "still5"),
        .init(title: "The Dark Knight", year: "2008", runtime: "2h 32m", certification: "UA", posterImage: "poster6", stillImage: "still6")
    ]
    @State var selectedItem: CarouselItem?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Popular films")
                    .font(.title2.bold())
                Spacer()
            }
            
            // MARK: Carousal
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                LazyHStack(spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
                        CarousalItemView(item: item, selectedItem: $selectedItem)
                            .frame(width: selectedItem?.id != item.id ? 150 : 250, height: 250)
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                            .contentShape(Rectangle())
                            .onTapGesture {
                                withAnimation {
                                    if selectedItem?.id == item.id {
                                        selectedItem = nil
                                    } else {
                                        selectedItem = item
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 250)
            .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
            .clipped()

            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .background {
            Color(.darkGray).ignoresSafeArea()
        }
        .foregroundStyle(.white)
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I can do that... I'll let you know

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm Mat again! I think I have what you are looking for. With just a few modifications to your code I was able to achieve the zoomy effect. I just used a scaleEffect and a few other tweaks here and there. First off edit your CarouselItemView like this:

```
var body: some View {
    let isSelected = item.id == selectedItem?.id
    ZStack {
        selectedItemView()
            .opacity(isSelected ? 1 : 0)
            .disabled(!isSelected) // <-- Disable buttons if the view is not selected
        
        unselectedItemView()
            .opacity(!isSelected ? 1 : 0)
    }
    .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: 10)) // To alway preserve rounded corners
    .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.3), value: item.id == selectedItem?.id) // Add animation here based on selectedItem changes
}
```

And add this line to your Image created in selectedItemView:

```
@ViewBuilder func selectedItemView() -> some View {
    let isSelected = item.id == selectedItem?.id
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        ZStack {
            Image(item.stillImage)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: 250, height: 200)
                .scaleEffect(isSelected ? 1.1 : 1, anchor: .center) // <-- Add this line to add the scale effect
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
/// Other code...
```

The scaleEffect I think is what makes it look the closest to waht you want. Play with the scale (maybe increase it a bit), the various animations curves and durations to tune it to perfection!

Heres the result:

[image: ScaleEffect]

Let me know your thoughts!