# Scroll to item with animation issue

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In a scrollview with `LazyHStack`, I'm running into an issue with smoothly scrolling a tapped item into view. This is the animation Im trying to achieve:

[image]

Note that the item hovered on above smoothly expands into view with items shifting on either side.

My scrollview item is structured such that it expands with animation on tap. However for a scroll view item that is partially visible, I'm unable to have it expand as well as scroll completely into view.

My code is as follows:

```
struct CarouselItem: Identifiable, Equatable {
    private(set) var id: UUID = .init()
    var title: String
    var year: String
    var runtime: String
    var certification: String
    var posterImage: String
    var stillImage: String
}

struct CarousalItemView: View {
    @State var item: CarouselItem
    @Binding var selectedItem: CarouselItem?
    @Namespace private var namespace
    private var expanded: Bool {
        item.id == selectedItem?.id
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ZStack {
                Image(item.posterImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .scaleEffect(expanded ?  1.5 : 1, anchor: .topLeading)
                    .frame(width: expanded ? 250 : 150, height: 200)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "image", in: namespace, anchor: .topLeading, isSource: true)
                    .opacity(expanded ? 0 : 1)
                    .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.3), value: expanded)
                
                Image(item.stillImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: expanded ? 250 : 150, height: 200)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "image", in: namespace, anchor: .topLeading, isSource: false)
                    .opacity(expanded ? 1 : 0)
                    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2).delay(expanded ? 0.1 : 0), value: expanded)
                    .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
                        if expanded {
                            itemDetailsView()
                        }
                    }
            }
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))

            Text(item.title)
                .frame(height: 50)
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder func itemDetailsView() -> some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15) {
            Spacer()
            Text(item.title)
                .font(.title2)
            HStack {
                Text("CBFC: " + item.certification)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                    .overlay {
                        Rectangle()
                            .stroke(.white, lineWidth: 1)
                    }
                Text(item.runtime)
                Text(item.year)
            }
            .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 5, y: 5)
            Button {

            } label: {
                Text("Trailer")
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            .tint(.gray)
            .padding(.bottom, 15)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var items: [CarouselItem] = [
        .init(title: "Oppenheimer", year: "2023", runtime: "3h 1m", certification: "UA", posterImage: "poster1", stillImage: "still1"),
        .init(title: "Barbie", year: "2023", runtime: "1h 54m", certification: "PG", posterImage: "poster2", stillImage: "still2"),
        .init(title: "The Martian", year: "2015", runtime: "2h 24m", certification: "UA", posterImage: "poster3", stillImage: "still3"),
        .init(title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: "1994", runtime: "2h 22m", certification: "U", posterImage: "poster4", stillImage: "still4"),
        .init(title: "The Godfather", year: "1972", runtime: "2h 55m", certification: "UA", posterImage: "poster5", stillImage: "still5"),
        .init(title: "The Dark Knight", year: "2008", runtime: "2h 32m", certification: "UA", posterImage: "poster6", stillImage: "still6")
    ]
    @State var selectedItem: CarouselItem?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Popular films")
                    .font(.title2.bold())
                Spacer()
            }
            
            // MARK: Carousal
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                    LazyHStack(spacing: 20) {
                        ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
                            CarousalItemView(item: item, selectedItem: $selectedItem)
                                .frame(width: selectedItem?.id != item.id ? 150 : 250, height: 250)
                                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                        withAnimation {
                                            if selectedItem?.id == item.id {
                                                selectedItem = nil
                                            } else {
                                                selectedItem = item
                                                guard let item = selectedItem else { return }
                                                proxy.scrollTo(item.id, anchor: .center)
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(height: 250)
                .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
                .clipped()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .background {
            Color(.darkGray).ignoresSafeArea()
        }
        .foregroundStyle(.white)
    }
}
```

In the code above, the animation is kind of jerky especially if an item is expanded and is partially visible at the left & right edges.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's you again! I'm the one from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77880279/animate-swiftui-scrollview-item-from-left-edge/77881585#77881585. You did not made me know anything. I'm gonna try help you again.

Comment: Hey @MatBuompy, I did not check your answer at the time as I later figured out how to do it using matchedGeometry which worked better rather than scale :) Nonetheless, I've marked it as the answer to thank you for your effort spent on my problem.

Comment: I'm working on the animation again. The issue I thing it's the scrollTo that seems not to suppoort animations so it moves rapidly. In case yoir minimum deployment target is iOS 17 there are new ScrollView APIs which could come in handy in solving the carousel change of position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to get the desired effect with some modifications viz. switching from a `LazyHStack` to an `HStack`, setting the `id` modifier to that of the item and doing the `scrollTo` animation with a minor delay. These changes got rid of the jankyness when clicking items that were partially visible in the view. I also removed all animation code from the images. The relevant code is as follows:

```
ScrollViewReader { proxy in
    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        HStack(spacing: 20) {
            ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
                CarousalItemView(item: item, selectedItem: $selectedItem)
                    .frame(width: selectedItem?.id == item.id ? 250 : 150, height: 250)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .id(item.id)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.4)) {
                                selectedItem = selectedItem?.id == item.id ? nil : item
                            }
                        }
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.4)) {
                                proxy.scrollTo(selectedItem?.id, anchor: .center)
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    .frame(height: 250)
    .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's exactly what you are looking for but, It is definetely a step closer. In this example I've been using iOS 17's new scroll view modifiers which makes our lives easier.
Note: It seems that for some reason unkown to me both the ScrollViewReader scrollTo function and new iOS 17 scrollPosition modifier are not affected in any way by animations. So I don't know of a easy way as of today to slower the scroll animation.
So, you kind of where already there with the result, I only changed a few things here and there. The animation durations here:

```
ZStack {
            Image(item.posterImage)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: expanded ? 250 : 150, height: 200)
                .scaleEffect(expanded ?  1.5 : 1, anchor: .center)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "image", in: namespace, anchor: .topLeading, isSource: true)
                .opacity(expanded ? 0 : 1)
                .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.8), value: expanded)
            
            Image(item.stillImage)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: expanded ? 250 : 150, height: 200)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "image", in: namespace, anchor: .topLeading, isSource: false)
                .opacity(expanded ? 1 : 0)
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.8).delay(expanded ? 0.2 : 0), value: expanded)
                .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
                    if expanded {
                        itemDetailsView()
                    }
                }
        }
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
```

And switched to the new iOS 17 APIs for the ScrollView to avoid use of ScrollViewReader. And here too, I just made a few tweaks here and there:

```
// MARK: Carousal
        //ScrollViewReader { proxy in
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            LazyHStack(spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
                    CarousalItemView(item: item, selectedItem: $selectedItem)
                        .frame(width: selectedItem?.id != item.id ? 150 : 250, height: 250)
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                        .contentShape(Rectangle())
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation(.smooth(duration: 0.8)) {
                                if selectedItem?.id == item.id {
                                    selectedItem = nil
                                } else {
                                    selectedItem = item
                                    guard let item = selectedItem else { return }
                                    
                                    /// Use this if supporting iOS previous to 17
                                    //proxy.scrollTo(item.id, anchor: .center)
                                }
                            }
                            
                            activeID = item.id
                        }
                }
            }
            .scrollTargetLayout(isEnabled: true)
            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
        }
        .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned) // (iOS 17+) Keeps the current carousel item aligned on screen
        /// Use anchor center to position the current carousel item at the center of the screen
        .scrollPosition(id: $activeID, anchor: .topLeading) // <-- use this to control the scroll position (Only works on iOS 17+)
        .frame(height: 250)
        .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
        .clipped()
        .animation(.smooth(duration: 2), value: activeID)
        // }
```

If your minimum deployment target is lower than iOS 17 you can uncomment the ScrollViewReader at anytime and get rid of the new stuff, it should work the same.
Here's the result:

[image: Carousel Animation]

Let me know if this can work out for you!

Comment: Thanks for trying out a solution. I was ultimately able to get it to work without the iOS 17 apis. I've posted my answer if you're interested.

Comment: I'll check it out.